# authentication laravel 8 jwt token override subject token

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, laravel-8

I have a problem with laravel 8 and jwt token here is a little background
I have two laravel 8 api with two databases on two different servers which I will call app 1 and app 2
and I must be able to auto connect with user 1 who has id 5 on app 1 and this same user exists but he has id 2 on app 2 but the reverse is not possible a user of app 2 cannot this connect to app 1 so sso is not possible unless I'm wrong? .
The problem is that laravel, but automatically id of the current user id 5 in the subject 'sub' of the token and I cannot overload this when I would have to give it id 2 in the ' sub 'of the token,
I manage to customize the token by adding email for example and I get the id of user 2 in the database of app 2, but each time laravel pass id of user 1, would anyone have an idea

Here is my code here at the login I will look in the DB for the user according to his email which is unique and I put in session the information that I retrieve and launch the autoload function which creates a new token

```
$app2User = DB::connection('mysql2')->table("users")->where('email', '=', $request->email)->pluck('id');
        if (count($app2User) > 0) {
            session(['app2UserId' => $app2User[0], 'app2UserEmail' => $request->email]);
            $this->autoload();

        } else {
            log::info('is null');
        }
        session(['optisiloUserEmail' => $request->email]);
        
         return $this->createNewToken($token);
```

Autoload function in which I put the token create in app2UserToken session to transmit it to my createNewToken function which sends me a json with the token of the current user and access_token to send to app2 for this connection

```
 public function autoload()
    {
        $id = session('optisiloUserId');
        $email = session('optisiloUserEmail');
        $payload = JWTFactory::sub($id)->email($email)->make();
        $token = JWTAuth::encode($payload);
        session(['app2UserToken' =>  $token->get()]);
    }
```

```
  protected function createNewToken($token)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'token' => $token,
            'access_token' => session('optisiloUserToken'),
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => Auth::factory()->getTTL() * 60,
            'user' => User::where('id', Auth::id())
        ]);
    }
}
```

I tried this in the User model but suddenly it works on app 2 but no longer on app1 because the sub takes user id from app 2
it is the function $this->getKey() which retrieves the primaryKey or id of the current user

```
 public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
     $id = $this->getKey();
        $res = User::where('id', $id)->pluck('id_user_app2')[0];
        if ($res === null) {
            return $this->getKey();
        } else {
            return $res;
        }
    }
```

how could we override the token's sub or or tell it who puts id 5 in the token and id 2 in access_token?

Comment: I think you need a central DB for a SSO service like that? Or you somehow get the correct id if you search for the Email?

Comment: @Aless55 No, I don't need sso I think because user id 5 has access to application 1 and 2 but user id 2 does not have access to application 1 just application 2

The two applications are on separate servers each with their own database.